# c# an unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: c#, error-handling, wmi

I am running WMI queries but I need a way to test that the connection is working properly before running any queries.

Below is the method that I created for to test the connection before running any query.

Any ideas on how I can test the connection for failure?

```
         private void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strPC = txtPCName.Text.ToString();
        string strDrive = txtDrive.Text.ToString();

        if (strPC == "" || strDrive == "" || txtUser.Text.ToString() == "" || txtPW.Text.ToString() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The PC Name/ Drive Letter / Username / Or Password is blank. Please make sure all of these fields are filled out");
        }
        else
        {
            //Set up the connection first and test that it is working properly
            ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
            connection.Username = txtUser.Text;
            connection.Password = txtPW.Text;
            connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:expd";

            ManagementScope mgmtScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + strPC + "\\root\\cimv2", connection);

            if (pTestWMIConnection(mgmtScope) == true)
            {
                //Get PC Information
                double dblMem = pGetMemUsage("FreePhysicalMemory", mgmtScope);
                double dblTotDisk = pGetTotalDiskSpace(strDrive, mgmtScope);
                double dblFreeDisk = pGetFreeDiskSpace(strDrive, mgmtScope);

                txtMem.Text = Math.Round(dblMem, 2).ToString() + " MB";
                txtDriveTot.Text = Math.Round(dblTotDisk, 2).ToString() + " GB";
                txtFreeDisk.Text = Math.Round(dblFreeDisk, 2).ToString() + " GB";
                txtSN.Text = pGetWMIInfo("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber", mgmtScope);
                txtIP.Text = pGetIPAddress("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration", "IPAddress", mgmtScope);
                txtModel.Text = pGetWMIInfo("Win32_ComputerSystem", "Model", mgmtScope);
                txtArch.Text = pGetWMIInfo("Win32_OperatingSystem", "OSArchitecture", mgmtScope);

                SetBalloonTip("Complete", "PC Query Completed");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to remote PC failed"); 
            }
        }           
    } 


 public static bool pTestWMIConnection(ManagementScope mgmtScope)
    {
        try
        {
            mgmtScope.Connect();

            if (mgmtScope.IsConnected == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        catch (ManagementException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Return some or all of the information requested - " + err.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedErr)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password might be incorrect - " + unauthorizedErr.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming your code doesn't work? Even though it returns true you still get an exception in some other code? Can we see the other code?

Comment: Yes correct. The catch works but only if the PC name has been entered in correctly. Say the user has a typing error when entering it into a text field, then it gets to the mgmtScope.Connect() and crashes. Yes let me post my main code

Answer (score 0):

If your program crashes inside the try catch statement, then it appears as if the return exception is not of type `ManagementException` or `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

Try instead, simply using `Catch(Exception ex)` which should catch ALL exceptions, then trigger the error by mistyping information and see what error type it is, then handle that.  Your error handling seems adequate with a message box and what I presume is kicking the routine back to the user to fix the input and resubmit, so I would mimic the same functionality with whatever error the system kicks out.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I just needed to add the exception error handler